# Has the amount of force/energy required to counter gravity the same scaling as energy required to reach lightspeed?

Tags: forces, acceleration, speed-of-light

First, I have no clue about physics outside of school so please don't mind if I use wrong terms in my question.

So on earth there is a force applied to everything towards the ground at $\sim 1g$, or $9.81 ~ m/s^{2}$. To counter this force and be at a "fixed point" I need to staticly apply $X$ amount of energy to the opposite side.

I have read that to accelerate an object with mass to lightspeed you need an infinite amount of energy to reach lightspeed.

Could the same be true in this scenario? If the attractive force goes torwards the speed of light ($299.792.458 ~ m/s^{2}$) the amount of energy required to counter this force goes to infinity?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't take any energy to counter gravity on Earth. Just stand on the ground, which applies a for $f=mg$. Integrating that force over the distance it is applied gives the work done:

$$ W = \int_{z=0}^{z=0} f dz = z|_0^0=0-0=0 $$

The idea that $299,792,458 {m/s^2}$ represents $c$ in some physical way is misguided. It's basically "c per second" of acceleration, which is unit dependent.

If I write $c$ as (roughly) $671$ million mph, I'd be inclined to use an acceleration of 671 million mph per hour...which is just different.

The only acceleration that is independent of the system, of units is the Planck acceleration:

$$ a_P = \sqrt{\frac{c^7}{\hbar G}}\approx 5\times 10^{51}\,{\rm m/s^2}$$

Regarding the acceleration towards light speed...there is no reaching light speed...requiring infinite energy is a common way to look at it, but I think it obscures the nature of relativity, as it implies an absolute rest frame from which to start the processes.

Suppose you want to reach 99.99 percent $c$ in two stages:

You start "at rest". If you send out a light/radio signal, it propagates away from you at $c$ in all directions. Now, accelerate to $0.99 c$ in $x$ direction... then coast.

In your new reference frame, you send out a signal that you are ready for stage 2. Well, that signal propagates away from you spherically in all directions at $c$. So....which way do you accelerate? The Galilean guess is the $x$-direction, but $c$ is the same distance away in all directions. The $-x$ direction is just as valid, which would bring you back home, at rest.

You simply cannot move with respect to space, and no matter how fast your are moving relative to someone else: you are at rest in your rest frame.

Finally, if you have an $n$-stage rocket, and always accelerate in the same direction: yes, the energy diverges as $n\rightarrow \infty$, but that doesn't really capture the hyperbolic nature of space-time.

It may or may not help to study M.C. Esher's Circle Limit III:

[image]

No matter how many stages (fish) you traverse, you never reach the circle..and your view is always from the center of the circle.

You can put some numbers to it by iterating the relativistic velocity addition formal:

$$ v + u \rightarrow \frac{v+u}{1 + \frac{uv}{c^2}} $$

or considering the rapidity:

$$ \omega = \tanh^{-1}\frac v c $$

which is additive in consecutive collinear boosts.

Answer (score 1):

To counteract a force, you must apply an equal and opposite force. No energy needs to be expended. When an apple sits on the a table, the upward force provided by the table counteracts the downward force of gravity, but the table does not do work on the apple and there is no energy being used up by the table to keep the apple stationary.

It's true that you would need an infinite amount of energy to accelerate a massive object to the speed of light, or more precisely that the energy required to accelerate an object to a given speed approaches infinity as the speed approaches $c$. The relativistic kinetic energy of an object with mass $m$ travelling at speed $v$ is equal to $(\gamma - 1)mc^2$, where $\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$. As $v$ approaches $c$ in this equation, $\gamma$ approaches infinity, and so the kinetic energy goes to infinity.

When you talk about an attractive force approaching the speed of light and give the value $299,792,458 \frac{m}{s^2}$, there's some confusion and mixing of concepts going on. The speed of light has units of length per time (in SI, $\frac{m}{s}$). It is not a force (SI units of $kg\frac{m}{s^2}$) or an acceleration ($\frac{m}{s^2}$). Speed, acceleration, and force are three separate physical properties that can't be equated like that. It seems like you're asking if there's an object with gravity so strong that no force can resist its pull. The answer is yes: it's called a black hole. Nothing travelling at or below light speed is able to escape a black hole's event horizon. If an unlucky rocket ship falls into one, it will not get out no matter how much force its thrusters apply.